# Convert rewrite rule from antlr3 to antlr4

Tags: parsing, antlr4, antlr3

I want to convert below rewrite rule.
cause I have to move from antlr3 to antlr4

```
abs_key
    :   {input.LT(1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("abs")}? REGULAR_ID -> ABS_VK[$REGULAR_ID]
    ;
```

In lexer

```
REGULAR_ID
    :    (SIMPLE_LETTER) (SIMPLE_LETTER | '$' | '_' | '#' | ':' | '0'..'9')*
    ;
```

Is there any good idea?

Comment: There are no rewrite rules in v4, and this has nothing to do with the lexer. I think you need to read the docs.

Comment: i think somebody already works on port of PL/SQL grammar onto Antr4. Use google.